# The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0

Tags: php, wordpress

I just updated to WordPress 4.3 and it seems that something is broken.

I get this error that shows up on my page:

> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use `__construct()` instead. in /mnt/stor13-wc1-ord1/754452/www.eden-festival.com/web/content/securewp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3457

Is there something that needs to be fixed?

Comment: You have a deprecated function in your `functions.php` you should change that. If you want help with it, we need to see the code.

Comment: That's strange.. I've just looked at my functions.php file inside my wp-includes folder, at this line.. and there's no constructor method being called.. although it lands right in the function that displays the error message in the admin. That's not right is it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since php 7 doesn't support php 4 object construct and was replaced with `__construct()` Wordpress developers created a notice message so the plugin developers would change the way their plugins work.
As php 4 has been dead for a very long time there's no reason to use this style of object construct.

## How to fix?

**Option 1 - not going to upgrade to newer php versions**

just add
`add_filter('deprecated_constructor_trigger_error', '__return_false');`

to your functions.php file it will ignore those notices.

**Option 2 - might upgrade to php 7 / prefer dealing with the issue rather than silencing it**

> > If this is a third party plugin, beware that if you make the change yourself and the plugin developer releases an update then it will override your changes. Contacting the plugin developer to fix this issue will be the best option

Find the problematic plugin and change:

`parent::WP_Widget`

To

`parent::__construct`

Comment: If this is a third party plugin, beware that if you make the change yourself, and they do an update, that doesn't include this.. it will reverse the change you made. You should contact the plugin author and request an update regarding this.

Comment: Thanks Gal,but i solved my issue simply edit single line in wp-config file.i just put  false  in debug mode and now everything is fine my site and my admin panel.

Comment: @aniruddh well you probably just silenced the warning which is the same as option 1,I would still contact the developer as I guess you would like to have php 7 when its out.

Comment: If your code includes **$this->WP_Widget(** you might have to change it to **parent::__construct(**

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where you add `add_filter('deprecated_constructor_trigger_error', '__return_false');`  I added mine just after the require statement at the start of functions.php file.  My functions.php file was located in the `public_html` -> `wp-includes` folder.

Comment: @Joe Don't modify core files!

Answer (score 30):

I am also getting the same error And I fixed it in such a way

```
class Dokan_Category_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     **/
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'dokan-category-menu', 'description' => __( 'Dokan product category menu', 'dokan' ) );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'dokan-category-menu', 'Dokan: Product Category', $widget_ops );
    }
}
```

As way of calling constructor in such way is deprecated in php 7, so I replaced calling way as `$this->WP_Widget()` with `parent::__construct()`

```
class Dokan_Category_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     **/
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'dokan-category-menu', 'description' => __( 'Dokan product category menu', 'dokan' ) );
        //$this->WP_Widget( 'dokan-category-menu', 'Dokan: Product Category', $widget_ops );
        parent::__construct('dokan-category-menu', 'Dokan: Product Category', $widget_ops  );
    }
}
```

Comment: I just test in my plugin and parent::__construct works perfectly, Now notices :) thanks @ganesh

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using some plugin that is not updated after wordpress updates and having some code like `class ***_Widget extends WP_Widget {` .you should update that plugin or deactivate it until It is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a function then calling the parent constructor resolved this issue for me.

```
class myClass extends WP_Widget {
  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct(...) // calls constructor from WP_Widget class
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its kind of warning you can hide the error  using add a line in your `wp-config.php` file in your site root directory

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Answer (score -5):

I experienced this issue and I found by changing the 'true' statement to 'false' in /wp-includes/functions.php it disabled the errors.

> if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters(
>   'deprecated_constructor_trigger_error', true ) ) {

Comment: do NOT modify core files!

Comment: It is not a good practice as a programmer to modify the core files in any framework.